# Преобразование списка конфигураторов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, html

Здравствуйте!

Имеется список Атомных конфигураторов, мне нужно немного преобразовать его, для более наглядного вида на сайте, чтобы проще было читать и ориентироваться. Как это сделать?

Пример:
Имеется конфигуратор на входе `1s2.2s2.3p6.(3D).5d` (строка).

Нужно преобразовать его в следующий вид:

```
1s<sup>2</sup>2s<sup>2</sup>3p<sup>6</sup>(<sup>3</supD>)5d
```

Comment: непонятно, действительно ли вам нужно убрать точки,

непонятно, что делать с ".(3D).",

а так:

    s|(?<=\d[A-Za-z])(\d)(\.)?|'<sup>'.$1.'</sup>'|ge

Comment: точки я могу и в конце убрать после обработки. Меня интересует только тот вид, который я получаю и должен получить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s = '1s2.2s2.3p6.(3D).5d';
$s = preg_replace('/((?<=[0-9][sp])[0-9]|(?<=\()[^\)]+(?=\)))/', '<sup>$1</sup>', $s);
```

После этой модификации, правда, в строке останутся разделяющие точки.

Comment: только все, что в скобке, тоже в sup уходит)